# How do I keep repeating an iteration in a for loop if a particular error is shown in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, terminal

I am running a command individually on multiple files in a directory using a bash script that uses a for loop. For certain files, the command gives an error and moves to the next file. I don't want the for loop to move to the next iteration if there is an error, rather I want it to retry the command on that particular file.

I know of the try except feature found in languages like Python but not sure how to incorporate it into my particular problem in commandline/bash scripting. Here is how the code looks:

```
for i in $(cat ./listID.txt)
do
    command on file $i
done
```

Here the listID.txt contains all the file IDs in the directory and the command is a particular bioinformatics software that I am using.

The error code is "Error, line 3: tried 100000 potential loci for entry, but could not avoid excluded regions.  Ignoring entry and moving on."

I don't want the for loop to move on, rather keep applying the command to the particular file i until I don't get the particular error mentioned above and only then move on to the next iteration/file.

Comment: So check `command` exit status and break, if it's status is nonzero. Read [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a variable?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)

Comment: To be clear, you want to move on for any error with text that doesn't exactly match that one? Or is an answer that repeats until you get *no* errors (like those already present) what you want?

Comment: [Don't use `for` to read lines](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy its only for that particular error. So don't move on if you get that error, until it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute the command in a while loop:

```
for i in ...; do 
    while ! command on file "$i"; do sleep 1; done
done
```

The sleep is useful if your command is failing immediately: it can be painful if you let it restart as quickly as it can.

Given the comment below, you can easily modify this to check for a particular error message:

```
for i in ...; do 
    while command on file "$i" 2>&1 |
        grep -q 'Error, line 3: tried 100000 potential loci for entry' 
    do sleep 1; done
done
```

This discards all output from command, but can be modified relatively easily to retain it.  (eg, `while command 2>&1 | awk '/Error msg/{rv=1} 1 END {exit !rv}`)

Comment: Instead of `while !`, you could use `until`. BTW, it's not considered in the question, but it might be good to have a limit on the number of tries on a particular file, in case there's something unrecoverably wrong (like bad formatting, file missing,...)

Comment: Should have been a little more specific, but I want it for the particular error I mentioned. So if you get the particular error, repeat the iteration, if not move on.

Comment: BTW, I believe the OP was quite explicit in the original question, and even the title ("a *particular* error is shown").

Comment: (also, *grumble* re: `for i in ...` when the OP clearly wants to read line-by-line; [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), &c).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I was unsure whether or not to address that, so I copped out and replaced the ugliness with `...`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a check using `while` loop to check the exit code of the command after every execution, keep inside inner while-loop unless `rc` is zero(success).

```
while read -r line ;do
    rc=1;
    while [[ $rc -ne 0 ]];
    do
        command on file "$line"
        rc=$?;
        #sleep 1;                       #this is optional, based on your environment
    done
done < ./listID.txt
```

PS: replaced `for loop` with `while loop`. Its not a very good practice to parse a file line-by-line using for loop.